# How to show system share button on mobile device? And hide desktop share buttons on same condition

Tags: javascript, html, css, amp-html

I'm programming responsive site, using Google Amp scripts, but have no ⚡ sign in html tag. This allows to speed up site, without using google cdn, also I'm violates some amp rules, using js for example. It really speed up using google scripts, even not properly.
Share button for mobile looks follows: (it appear only on mobiles)

```
<amp-social-share type="system" width="36" height="36" id="shareLink" style="float: right;">
        <amp-img src="/i/Share-128.png"  width="36" height="36" style="float: right;"></amp-img>
</amp-social-share>
```

**How to hide other share buttons block**, depending on device but not screen width?
The above code works opposite to what I need. Share button appear on mobile, but not on desktop. As this system share button this provides greater functionality on mobile.

I'm using media queries in css, but only with size parameters to make site responsive.

*Looking for javascript or css solution compatible with all modern browsers.*
Also, it very interesting for me, how to make system share button without google-amp.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xsht8t?file=src/app/app.component.ts) You can use [ngx-devie-detector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-device-detector)

After install it import to component

```
  import { DeviceDetectorService } from 'ngx-device-detector';
```

and then you can reach info of device

```
deviceInfo = null;
  constructor( private deviceService: DeviceDetectorService){
    this.deviceInfo = this.deviceService.getDeviceInfo();
    console.log(this.deviceInfo)
  }
```

at final you can hide or show with using ngIf or using class and css